# 12 V power supply for blower motor

Tags: power-supply, 12v

I'm looking for a power supply to run a small propane RV furnace. The furnace only draws about 5 A while operating, to run its blower motor and the electronic ignitor plus the circuit board that controls the unit. I bought an 8 A power supply from AliExpress similar to the one shown. Just wondering if this type of power supply is recommended to be used with the furnace or if another type would be more appropriate.

[image: 8 A, 12 V power supply, made in China]

Comment: probably the *recommended* one is whatever came with the furnace. But yeah, if it says 12V 5A, then a 12V 8A supply will probably do. Make sure the connector is the right connector; make sure the + and - are the right way around; else you might need to re-wire it. I can't foresee everything, so maybe there's a chance maybe the inrush current is too high and the supply doesn't handle it, but that's more of a problem for big motors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8A nameplate rating should be sufficient to run a 5A circuit (though the motor starting surge might trip some internal protection), but the furnace manufacturer should tell you the recommended power supply to use - I suspect they'll tell you to use their own marked-up brick.  Aside from that, it's up to you if you want to have the motor, igniter, and control board for a furnace in a RV you are presumably sleeping in powered by a supply from AliExpress which is not known for its commitment to quality.

Comment: Thanks, to clarify these furnaces are typically installed in an RV and powered directly from a deep cycle battery. In my case I'm installing in an outbuilding that has 120vac available. So I'm already outside the bounds on the manufacturer recommendation here, their manual/spec sheet makes no mention of any power supply requirement and if asked they probably would recommend running from a battery like they intended. Just mainly wanted to clarify if motors needed a certain kind of power supply or if these typical electronics type PSU's will work in the long term. Def agree on the quality issues